# Email item replaces russian text with question marks

Tags: c#, outlook

When i pass text in russian language in subject/body. The text is replaced with question marks in the opened email message.

I am using MAPI from code project reference https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17561/Programmatically-adding-attachments-to-emails-in-C

I tried using mailto, it sets the text as i pass to it but **i can't add attachments using mailto**:

```
    string mailto = string.Format("mailto:?cc={0}&Subject={1}&Body={2}&attachment={3}", ccEmailId, subject, body, attachmentPath);
    mailto = Uri.EscapeUriString(mailto);
    Process proc = Process.Start(mailto);
```

With some research i found that using outlook interop can be a workaround but i am not sure what email client will be set as default on end user machine.

Settings in outlook on dev machine:
!https://ibb.co/b5XK5rV

Is there any other way so that i can set attachments on the mail message and launch the email dialogue while passing text in any language that will not be converted to question marks(??????).

Comment: this maybe due to encoding, since western europe may not support russian characters

Comment: i  tried changing the encoding to utf-8 but it have same behavior..shows question marks for Russian text

Comment: what encoding has the string you are passing to mapi? There are some "weird" russian encodings which may need to be converted first

Comment: I also tried installing russian language and setting is as default for editing and display language..still it shows ?? for russian text added from MAPI

Comment: I do not have any encoding on the string, i receive the string message from another service and directly pass to the MAPI. the mapimessage class is as below:[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
            public class MapiMessage
            {
            } @SebastianL

Comment: And there is the Problem: ANSI doesn't contain any russian characters

Answer (score 1):

All non-ASCII and Unicode characters must be url-encoded:

```
mailto:test@example.com?Subject=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82
```

Comment: using mailto i can see the russian text with out using any encoding. Problem with mailto is that i can't set any attachments on the mail item.

Comment: You cannot add attachments using the mailto protocol.

Answer (score 0):

due to the foreign characters you may want to use UTF 16

here is a complete list for all characters.

https://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-16/list.htm

Comment: outlook do not have any option to use UTF-16 encoding. I am using outlook 2016

Comment: using mailto: i can put russian character in the mail body, i think this is related to mapi only